# Google Firebase: snap.val().username returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I get the item in the realtime database where the email child equals the email in the localStorage and that works just fine.

however when i try to log the username, it returns undefined instead of the actual username

```
let useremail = localStorage.getItem("useremail")

    firebase.database().ref("/users").orderByChild('email').equalTo(useremail).on("value", function(snap){
        let data = snap.val();
        console.log(data.username)
    })
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

database looks like this

[image: database looks like this]

If i log data this shows:
[image]

and If i log useremail the correct string does show

Comment: What exactly is the value of `useremail`? Be sure to log it.  Also, what does `console.log(data)` show?  Are you sure you've actually matched a user in your query?

Comment: I've updated the question with the answers to your questions, doug, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
let useremail = localStorage.getItem("useremail")

firebase.database().ref("/users").orderByChild('email').equalTo(useremail).on("value", function(snap){
snap.forEach(function(childSnapshot)){
    let data = childSnapshot.val();
    console.log(data.username)
 });
});
```

Since reference is at node `users` then you need to loop to be able to access the attributes.

Comment: The reason the loop is needed is that when you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Comment: Yes it is the same as looping in android `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` @FrankvanPuffelen